# Top align content of a table in beamer

Tags: tables, pdftex, media9

I am trying to include a media inside a table as:

```
\item \begin{tabular}[t!]{p{5cm}l}
    some text here &
    \includemedia[
      activate=onclick,
      width=0.45\textwidth
    ]{\includegraphics{msmini.png}}{crop.mp4}\\
  \end{tabular}
```

The aim is to have two column in same `top aligned` position inside the `item`. But the first column is layed after the end of the media:
[image: as shown here]

Is it possible to align them at top?

Comment: You can not have a `!` in a tabular argument.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item \begin{tabular}{p{5cm}l}
    some text here &
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includemedia[
      activate=onclick,
      width=0.45\textwidth
    ]{\includegraphics{example-image}}{example-image}}
  \end{tabular}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, without additional package, use a \raisebox:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item \begin{tabular}{p{5cm}l}
    some text here &
    \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includemedia[
      activate=onclick,
      width=0.45\textwidth
    ]{\includegraphics{example-image}}{example-image}}\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

By the way, the optional argument for tabular admits `t`, `c`, `b`, but no `!` can be used there.